# 2000 Reputation points to edit questions and answers?

Tags: support

In [Privileges](https://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit), it says I need 2000 Reputation points to be able to edit questions and answers.

However, at my current level below 2000 points, I am already able to do this. Or, is my understanding wrong?

Comment: You have enough now though ;)

Comment: @LiamW I was still below 2K when I asked this question. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure that you are able to make edits that don't need prior approval before they are applied?

Every user can make 'suggested edits' but if you have >2000 rep you are don't need to get the approval of the community first. In fact you should then be able to review suggested edits yourself.

Comment: I see. So there's a review process. I get it now. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can edit questions and answers, but they go to a queue, from which moderators and users with enough reputation (over 2000) can accept, discard or improve your edits.

From the [Edit questions and answers privilege page](https://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit):

> **Reviewing suggested edits**
>
> In addition, users with this privilege level also get access to the
>   suggested edits queue. The queue has a list of posts which have been
>   edited upon by users who don't have edit privileges. This queue can be
>   accessed over at the suggested edits tab in the review section. Users
>   with this privilege level get access to the Low Quality Posts list
>   where they can improved the low quality posts, or suggest they are
>   deleted.